# Is there an SVN client we can use for Maven that supports picking up credentials from Jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, nexus

We use the Maven-release-plugin to perform releases and that invokes SVN to commit changes to poms, create branches etc. 
Currently to make this process happen we login with SVN client from command line and cached password in the .subversion folder of the user. 
Is there a way e.g. different maven plugin, different SVN client etc. for us to do this with having the credentials in Jenkins only.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can use the [Crendentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) for such purposes.

Within a pipeline you can do it via the following:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'amazon',
                usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', 
                passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
                //available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it out any which way
                sh 'mvn -Dusername=${USERNAME}, -Dpassword=${PASSWORD}  release:prepare release:perform'
            }
```

You can also add supplemental parameters during [release:perform](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html) via:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'amazon',
                usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', 
                passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
                sh 'mvn -Darguments="-Dusername=${USERNAME}, -Dpassword=${PASSWORD}" release:perform'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Credentials Binding Plugin in the build environment tick "Use secret text(s) or file(s). Then select username and password(separated) and select the credentials. 
In the "Username Variable" just input username
In the "Password Variable" just input password
The plugin will automatically inject the values from the credentials and hide them in the logs.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to read and reply to this.